# __hardfp_xxx symbols from ARM compiler not found by gcc linker

Tags: gcc, floating-point, arm

This is on a Raspberry Pi 3. I have a makefile that links a bunch of object files generated locally using gcc, with a static library that is generated on a different machine using the ARM tool chain. The ARM compiler uses the hard-float abi, which appears to be supported on the RPi 3. Everything builds and runs fine as long as the C code that goes into the static library is fixed point, but I get linker errors when the C code uses floating-point arithmetic. The gcc linker complains about missing symbols of the form __hardfp_xxx (e.g. __hardfp_pow). It looks like I might be missing a gcc library, but I can't figure out which one(s). Can anyone help?
Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think it is a missing gcc library? Could it not also be a missing ARM compiler library since you are linking against a library generated by that compiler? Have you checked to unresolved references from the static library against which you are linking?

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. I am new to cross-compiling so I might well be missing something. But if I link the static library (with the rest of the project code, that I ultimately need to build with gcc on the RPi3) with the arm linker on the machine used to generate the static library, then everything is okay. So the ARM tool chain seems to have these hardfp functions somewhere (in a library, I imagine), but gcc doesn't. Hence my speculation.

Comment: Okay, so the missing symbols are resolved by ARM compiler supplied libraries. This is not surprising to me. Different compilers have different functions that are internally generated. Seems to me that you need to find the ARM compiler library and use it in your gcc link. Just looks like a potential minefield. A new version of the ARM compiler will require you to hunt down its compiler library and reincorporate it into your gcc link. Very rocky area you are treading on.

Comment: Okay yes this makes sense. Thanks for the pointer. I'll try that and report back. And thanks for the words of caution, too!